# Insert data into mysql database with LIKE Clause

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdatechooser

I am developing simple swing application to get some information from the database. 
Two of the field in database table called Used_PR & Create_PR. 
As follows,[image]

Data structure is like mention below.

```
  PR-L-Machine-Date-Shift
```

Then I want to retrieve data by PR.
Here is my interface to insert search details[image]

Date choose from date JDateChooser.
I used LIKE clause to get data from the db, but it does not work.
Here is the MYSQL query statement.

```
        String prlQuery = "SELECT * FROM final_report WHERE used_PR LIKE '?%' OR create_PR LIKE '?%'";

        try {
            Date chooseDate = new Date(dateChooser.getDate().getTime());
            String parameter = "PR-L-" + selectMachine.getSelectedItem() + "-" + chooseDate;

            pst = connect.dbConnection().prepareStatement(prlQuery);
            pst.setString(1, parameter);
            pst.setString(2, parameter);
```

But seems it is not working. Can somebody help me with this code structure.

Comment: try to change the query to "SELECT * FROM final_report WHERE used_PR LIKE ? OR create_PR LIKE ?", and add the % at the end of the parameter string builder

Comment: You probably need to check the format of the date used stored in the database and format which you are currently getting from the JDateChooser.

Comment: I tried & it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the % in the parameters
your query must look like

```
 String prlQuery = "SELECT * FROM final_report WHERE used_PR LIKE ? OR create_PR LIKE ?";

    try {
        Date chooseDate = new Date(dateChooser.getDate().getTime());
        String parameter = "PR-L-" + selectMachine.getSelectedItem() + "-" + chooseDate;

        pst = connect.dbConnection().prepareStatement(prlQuery);
        pst.setString(1, parameter+"%");
        pst.setString(2, parameter+"%");
```

Comment: Happy to help you bro